# Kinect recording a video in C# WPF

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to record my kinect camera vision.I have searched, but I couldn't find any C# same core codes. Do you have same simple codes or same suggestions? thanks.

Comment: It is extremely easy using the Kinect SDK.  However it is not streaming video, it is still frames captured at 30fps.  Do a Google search for the Kinect SDK, there are videos and guides to help on the official site.

Comment: You are right,I know Kinect only gets 30 frames per seconds.Just frames not a video. But, I have to record  this frames, if it is possible? Can I do that. I mean Can I save every frame and then later can I show this frames consecutively,just a video?Is it possible or not. I really need this. Thanks.

Comment: It will be done using new version of Kinect SDK 1.5 refer this link and read about the new features http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Special-Edition-Kinect-for-Windows-SDK-v15-now-available

Answer (score 1):

I believe the AForge library may be of use to you. Here: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/ffmpeg.html you can see how you can instantiate a VideoFileWriter and write individual frames into it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this kinect record library for the kinect Kinect toolbox library

http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/

and here is a tutorial
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/07/04/gestures-and-tools-for-kinect.aspx

Comment: The KinectToolbox has utility functions to save the **Skeleton** stream, not the RGB/Depth streams. The Skeleton stream is stored as a text file, so it isn't helpful at all to generate a video.